# how can I predict an output from a pytorch model I have trained and saved?

Tags: python

I have trained and saved a model using my video dataset for a seq2seq sign language recognition(SLR) using a code from git-hub (https://github.com/0aqz0/SLR)

I created a pyTorch Model to classify images. I saved it once via state_dict and the entire model like that:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model1_statedict")
torch.save(model, "model1_complete")
```

And I loaded my model:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

and it works just fine but I don't know how get predictions out of it with my video input.

I don't know much about torch, so I don't know how to get output from my trained model as the authors did not it in their publicly available code.

so now I need help ,on how to get my output from my model.

PS:My model takes a video input and outputs a sentence-level text("Hello, how are you?")

Comment: Just call `your_model.forward(your_data)`

Answer (score 0):

Define your model class first (in your case it is already defined). And load back what you saved.

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

See very detailed explanations [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html).

Comment: Thanks for support. I loaded my model and working pretty good but I kindly request you to show me how to code how to get my text predictions with my input video.